# Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH

Tags: php

Este aviso

> Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH

muestra apuntando a esta línea `define(ROOT_PATH, __DIR__);` el mismo que estoy usando para incluir archivos PHP, porque se muestra el aviso, que estoy haciendo mal.

```
  define(ROOT_PATH, __DIR__);
  include ROOT_PATH . '/config.ini.php';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas en la [documentacion de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php), notarás que la definición de constantes se hace de este modo

```
define("VALOR_ALGO", "su valor");
```

Por lo que el error se puede dar en función de que PHP tiene constantes predefinidas en su núcleo, entonces tú al no usar comillas provocas que el intérprete busque en las existentes y como claramente no forma parte de pues te regresa ese error